# Overriding WooCommerce CSS issues

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having trouble overriding the default styling that comes with WooCommerce. Specifically, I am trying to hide certain fields that display on my checkout page (see screenshot of the code). I mocked up my page on Code Pen and my css is working fine, so I am not sure why it doesn't work on my styles.css of my child theme. Any help is appreciated!

```
.variation li div:first-child  {
display: none; }
```

https://codepen.io/jagorski/pen/oZBYrd

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clear the browser cache & try this:

```
.variation-JobListing:first-child  {
    display: none !important;
}
```